# How to make fields disappear after focusing out

Tags: jquery

I have radio buttons, that open 3 different divs (one at a time)

In the second div, I added 4 text inputs, so that each one should be open after clicking in the previous one (click(function())).  Once they are opened, I want it to hide again when I select the other radio button and the actual div hides.

How this can be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).fadeIn(2000);
    });
    //fim
    //inicio
    $("#campo1").click(function(){
        $("#musicinfo").show("slow")
    });
    //fim
    //inicio
    $("#musicinfo").click(function(){
        $("#music2").show("slow")
    });
    //fim
    //inicio
    $("#music2").click(function(){
        $("#music3").show("slow")
    });
    //fim
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<body>

2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />
3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />
4 cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="4" />

<div id="Cars2" class="desc">
    2 Cars Selected
</div>
<div id="Cars3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="campo1"><br>
    <div id="musicinfo"><input type="text" id="xxx" name="non"/></div>
    <div id="music2"><input type="text" id="eee" name="uuu"/></div>
    <div id="music3"><input type="text" id="www" name="ttt"/></div>
</div>
<div id="Cars4" class="desc" style="display: none;">
    4 Cars
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .hide() https://api.jquery.com/hide/
You can show, so probably you can hide. :)

On focusout, that is.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the focusout event...

Read this... http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

That should set you on tracks